# PHP Embed Image In HTML Email

Tags: php, html, image, email, html-email

I can successfully send a generic email using this script. However, when I add the code to show the logo at the top of the email in the header, everything bombs out. I get an HTTP error. I think it has something to do with the quotation marks.

```
$to = $email;
    $subject = "My Website Email Confirmation";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website Email Confirmation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo_transparent_background.png" height="70px">
        </header>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Welcome to My Website. We are excited to be working with you. Please click here to confirm your email address.
        <br>
        <br>Best regards, <br>Your Team
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <noreply@mywebsite.com>' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Please test by writing HTML codes in the same line and use single quotes inside the open and close double quotes.

Comment: Yes, ignore email for now and get `$message` to be a valid PHP variable that holds valid HTML

Comment: Or look at HEREDOC syntax: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Just an aside comment, Look into [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) , it will make things easier for you.

Comment: This did not work: $message = "<html><head><title>My Website Email Confirmation</title></head><body><header><img src="'https://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo_transparent_background.png" height="70px'"></header><br><br><p>Welcome to My Website. We are excited to be working with you. Please click here to confirm your email address.<br><br>Best regards, <br>Your Team</p></body></html>";

Comment: As others have said, but perhaps is not clear, the double quotes in src=" is breaking the code. Use src=', not src="'. Or, if you find it easier, use $message = '....'; (single quotes) then you can keep using double quotes inside $message.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PHPMailer. Albeit a little confusing at first, it ended up working well. I do not use this stuff every day so I needed to take a minute to wrap my head around it. I followed a couple YouTube videos to get there. It required installation on my web server:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM630O5W-_I

Then clarified a couple coding issues, especially the image related ones on these:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZamAho2_vcM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRwW3l6dhSE

https://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/send-mail-using-phpmailer-en/

After (1) installing it on the web server and (2) using the resources above to better understand the code, this code is working for me:

```
require "phpmailertesting/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body)
{
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = 'mail.mywebsite.com';
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->Username = 'autoreply@ mywebsite.com';
$mail->Password = '##############';

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/logo_transparent_background.png', 'logoimg');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From="autoreply@ mywebsite.com";
$mail->FromName=$from_name;
$mail->Sender=$from;
$mail->AddReplyTo($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
                $error ="Please try Later, Error Occured while Processing...";
                return $error; 
            }
            else 
            {
                $error = "Thanks You !! Your email is sent.";  
                return $error;
            }
    }
    
$to   = $email;
$from = 'autoreply@ mywebsite.com';
$name = 'My Website';
$subj = 'My Website Email Confirmation';
$msg = '<h1><img src=cid:logoimg height="70px"></h1><br>'
.'<p>Greetings, we are looking forward to working with you!"</p><br>'
.'<p>Please <a href="https://www. mywebsite.com/validateemail.php">click here</a> to validate your email address.</p><br>'
.'<p>Once that is complete, we are ready to start your customized plan!</p><br>'
.'<p>Or, you can <a href="https://www. mywebsite.com/signin.php">sign-in</a> here once confirmed.<br>'
.'<p>Best regards,</p><br>'
    .'<p>Your Team</p><br>';

$error=smtpmailer($to,$from, $name ,$subj, $msg);
```